# jQuery passing a value of an <a> to its target page

Tags: jquery

I am trying to pass a value once an  tag (created in jQuery) is clicked.
However, I tried some methods like using of `.data()` but can't get it to work.

I have to dynamically add the topic data and for each to have it's own containing `div`

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var topicId = topicData[i]['topicId'];
    var topicTitle = topicData[i]['topicTitle'];
    var topicDiv = $('<div></div>');
    var topicLink = $('<a>' + topicTitle+ '</a>').addClass('topic_link').attr('href','view/student_learn_topiclink.php').attr('target','_blank');
    var btnStartPretest = $('<button> Start Pretest </button>');
    var btnStartPostTest = $('<button> Start PostTest </button>');
    topicDiv.append(topicLink);
    topicDiv.append(btnStartPretest);
    topicDiv.append(btnStartPostTest);
    $(".allContent_Container").append(topicDiv);
}
```

I'm having problems with this line

```
$('<a>' + topicTitle+ '</a>').addClass('topic_link').attr('href','view/student_learn_topiclink.php').attr('target','_blank');
```

I tried to add `..attr('target','_blank').data(topicId)` but it won't work. 
I need to pass the value of `topicId` to the target `href` on anchor click.

I'd appreciate any suggestion.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you want the value to be applied clicking the link? If get parameter, just use `.attr('href','view/student_learn_topiclink.php?topicId=' + topicId)`

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't put topicId into attr also:

```
.attr("topicId",topicId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with ES6 solution

```
topicLink = `<a class="topic_link" href="view/student_learn_topiclink.php?topicId=${topicId}" target="_blank">${topicTitle}</a>`;
```

Comment: Hey thanks. I'm gonna go try it and update this question.

Comment: I am sorry for contacting you this way (my comment isnt related to your input here). I came across a question you voted on in "triage" where you made the wrong choice. Please: study the help for triage carefully, to avoid putting items into the edit queue that don't belong there. I hope you see this as a chance to improve your voting. I am specifically talking about https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21087068. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me. If you give me a quick reply, I will immediately this comment here.